# yaml.dump adding unwanted newlines in multiline strings

Tags: python, serialization, pyyaml

I have a multiline string:

```
>>> import credstash
>>> d = credstash.getSecret('alex_test_key', region='ap-southeast-2')
```

To see the raw data (first 162 characters):

```
>>> credstash.getSecret('alex_test_key', region='ap-southeast-2')[0:162]
u'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx\nxk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45\n'
```

And:

```
>>> print d[0:162]                                                                                                                                                                                          
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx
xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
```

I write to a YAML file:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> with open('foo.yaml', 'w') as f:                                                                                                                                                                        
...     yaml.dump(d, f, default_flow_style=False, explicit_start=True)
...
```

Now it looks like this:

```
$ head -5 foo.yaml 
--- !!python/unicode '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

  MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx

  xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
```

i.e. each line has two newlines.

Now if I read it back into a string I see that all is okay in the round-trip:

```
>>> with open('foo.yaml', 'r') as f:
...     d = yaml.load(f)
... 
>>> print d[0:162]
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx
xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
```

(I don't understand why however.)

My real problem is that if humans read this YAML file they will probably assume, as I did, that my program has broken the formatting of the private key file.

Is there a way to use yaml.dump so as to output something without the additional newline characters?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If that is the only thing going into your YAML file then you can dump with the option `default_style='|'` which gives you block style literal for all of your scalars (probably not what you want).

Your string, contains no special characters (that need `\` escaping and double quotes), because of the newlines PyYAML decides to represented single quoted. In single quoted style a double newline is the way to represent a single newline that occurred in string that is represented. This gets "undone" on loading, but is indeed not very readable.

If you want to get the block style literals on an individual basis, you can do multiple things:

- adapt the Representer to output all strings with embedded newlines using the literal scalar block style (assuming they don't need `\` escaping of special characters, which will force double quotes)

  ```
  import sys
  import yaml

  x = u"""\
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx
  xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
  ...
  """

  yaml.SafeDumper.org_represent_str = yaml.SafeDumper.represent_str

  def repr_str(dumper, data):
      if '\n' in data:
          return dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')
      return dumper.org_represent_str(data)

  yaml.add_representer(str, repr_str, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)

  yaml.safe_dump(dict(a=1, b='hello world', c=x), sys.stdout)
  ```
- make a subclass of string, that has its special representer. You should be able to take the code for that from [here](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/8063274df32921a9ebf25eeba6227d889f1d8c6d/scalarstring.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#scalarstring.py-26), [here](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/8063274df32921a9ebf25eeba6227d889f1d8c6d/representer.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#representer.py-1012) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/8063274df32921a9ebf25eeba6227d889f1d8c6d/representer.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#representer.py-660):

  ```
  import sys
  import yaml

  class PSS(str):
      pass

  x = PSS("""\
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx
  xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
  ...
  """)

  def pss_representer(dumper, data):
          style = '|'
          # if sys.versioninfo < (3,) and not isinstance(data, unicode):
          #     data = unicode(data, 'ascii')
          tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'
          return dumper.represent_scalar(tag, data, style=style)

  yaml.add_representer(PSS, pss_representer, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)

  yaml.safe_dump(dict(a=1, b='hello world', c=x), sys.stdout)
  ```
- use `ruamel.yaml`:

  ```
  import sys
  from ruamel.yaml import YAML
  from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import PreservedScalarString as pss

  x = pss("""\
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx
  xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
  ...
  """)

  yaml = YAML()

  yaml.dump(dict(a=1, b='hello world', c=x), sys.stdout)
  ```

All of these give:

```
a: 1
b: hello world
c: |
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx
  xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
  ...
```

Please note that it is not necessary to specify `default_flow_style=False` as the literal scalars can only appear in block style.

Comment: Not work for `x = '\"key:value\",\n \n'`
`

Comment: You should post a new question with a full program and ask what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Saved my day  adapting the Representer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto Anthon's answer, I found some documentation for other options I can pass to `default_style` at this link [here](https://dpinte.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/pyaml-dump-option/).

The best compromise I could find for representing all of my data was:

```
with open('foo.yaml', 'w') as f:
  yaml.safe_dump(secrets, f, explicit_start=True, default_style='\"', width=4096)
```

And this led to a YAML file that looks like:

```
---
"alex_test": "yyyyyyyy"
"alex_test_key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\n+fDJX+yvxnZsY5hw6cYwC3C/axS9jq63oQ7i8FXwG/a0breCGu8=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

I would have preferred to use ruamel.yaml, but this code must run in an environment where I can only use the default Python packages that I have available.

Comment: Also added code for how to do this in PyYAML for the first option. Done updating, back to work.

Comment: Well thank you again -- that's a really great reference for the next person who needs to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Better `ruamel.yaml` option for outputting multiline strings as blocks:

```py
from ruamel.yaml.representer import RoundTripRepresenter
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

multiline_string = """\
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx
xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
...
"""


def repr_str(dumper: RoundTripRepresenter, data: str):
    if '\n' in data:
        return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data)


yaml = YAML()
yaml.representer.add_representer(str, repr_str)

with open('file.yaml', 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump({'a': 1, 'b': 'hello world', 'c': multiline_string}, fp)
```

Output:

```yaml
a: 1
b: hello world
c: |
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA6oySC+8/N9VNpk0gJS7Gk8vn9sYN7FhjpAQnoHRqTN/Oaiyx
  xk2AleP2vXpojA/DHldT1JO+o3j56AHD+yfNFFeYvgWKDY35g49HsZZhbyCEAB45
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file named "privateKey.pem" with your key you could extract the content into a YAML multiline block with a '|' and 2 spaces indentation:

```
# Convert To yaml multiline block
cat privateKey.pem | sed -e '1 i PRIVATE_KEY: |' -e 's#^#  #g' > parameters.yaml

cat <<_EOF_ >>parameters.yaml
SSH_HOST: 'host.name.or.ip'
SSH_USER: 'cloud-user'
_EOF_
```

You get something like:

```
PRIVATE_KEY: |
  -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  b3BlbnNzaC1rZXkt....
  ...
SSH_HOST: 'host.name.or.ip'
```

Then in your shell script reading from parameters.yaml file

```
# Read values From Yaml using “PyYAML”
FILE=parameters.yaml

KEY=PRIVATE_KEY
python3 -c "from yaml import load; f = open('$FILE'); y = load(f); print(y['$KEY'])" > priv.key
chmod 600 priv.key

KEY=SSH_HOST
ssh_host=$(python3 -c "from yaml import load; f = open('$FILE'); y = load(f); print(y['$KEY'])")

KEY=SSH_USER
ssh_user=$(python3 -c "from yaml import load; f = open('$FILE'); y = load(f); print(y['$KEY'])")

# test
ssh -i priv.key ${ssh_user}@${ssh_host} "hostname"
```

More details in https://yaml-multiline.info/